# Is it possible in Eclipse to highlight a statement, and then press quotes/etc.. to "wrap" the highlighted text in the character (like in SublimeText)?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm coming from Sublime Text to Eclipse. One of my favorite feature of ST is highlighting a piece of text, and then being able to wrap it in quotations or parenthesis by pressing the appropriate key.

That probably poorly explains the functionality, so here's a gif example:

[image]

So, as you can see, if you highlight a piece of text, and then, in this example, press `(` it will wrap the highlighted text in parenthesis.

When I try this in Eclipse, highlighting the text, and then pressing `(` simply replaces what I highlighted rather than wrapping it up.

Is there a way to get this functionality inside of Eclipse?

Comment: Here is a list of the most common shortcuts in Eclipse: http://dcg.ethz.ch/lectures/ss07/vs/material/EclipseShortcuts.pdf

Comment: I am afraid this feature is not implemented yet. But you are welcome to open enhancement request to eclipse team or to implement your own plug-in that does this.

Comment: This feature exists in Aptana. So there must be a way to implement it due to Aptana is based on Eclipse

Answer (score 3):

Highlight the text, cut it (ctrl x), type quotes, paste text (ctrl v).

It's kind of a lame solution but it's faster since eclipse creates both quotes and puts cursor in the middle.

Comment: Simple trick, thanks. I can't believe that after so many years it is not "fixed" yet!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this functionality is in Eclipse by default, but you could try to add it yourself.

Select the block that you want to surround and press Alt+Shift+Z. This will open the "Surround with..." menu. It suggests some predefined templates, but also allows to add new ones. This is the closest of what Eclipse offers for that.

Comment: I just wanna say that this is a really shitty workaround (good answer, though) because literally the whole point is that you can quickly and easily wrap things in brackets without opening menus or doing four keypresses.

Comment: This only works in certain editors, go to 'Window > Preferences > General > Keys' and search for 'Surround' to see which.

Comment: Meh! _Aptana Studio 3_ has this implemented. Not sure how to get this in Eclipse-Neon!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a way to to obtain exactly this, but if you want to surround the text with quotes, here's how to. Go to:

```
Source -> Surround With...  -> Configure Templates
```

Create a new template, use `brackets` as name, and this as pattern:

```
(${word_selection})${cursor}
```

You can then obtain the functionality you wanted by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> **+** <kbd>SPACE</kbd> and then chose your template.